# python use the string as not string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I usually get the url like this

```
response.url
```

I also get more date from the response.

I wonder if there is a way in which I can pass the things that I want and then use it in the response like this:

```
x = 'url'
return response.x
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
x = "url"
return getattr(response, x)
```

From the docs:

> `getattr(object, name[, default])`
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. `name` must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, `default` is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: You should add the default argument, otherwise this will raise an exception. I forgot about the default third argument.

Comment: It only raises an exception if the named attribute isn't there. In some cases, leaving it to raise an error is the correct behaviour, hence it is an optional argument.